# Call sql stored procedure from Python - Error: ('42000', 'Error converting data type varchar to int. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Tags: python, stored-procedures

I am trying to call sql stored procedure from python, I have input and output parameters. But i am getting different error everytime. I am newbie to this. Any pointers are very helpful.

```
'''
cursor = conn.cursor()
execsp = "EXEC stored_procedure 'null'"
conn.autocommit = True
cursor.execute(execsp)
'''
```

This is giving error : ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to int. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Giving just:

```
'''
cursor.execute("stored_procedure")'''
```

is throwing the errors:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'stored_procedure' expects parameter 'outputparameter', which was not supplied. (201) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

The stored procedure has 4 input parameters and 1 output parameter. ANy pointer would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance